# How get rows berween desired days properly?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have the dataframe that has:

- Objects;
- Alarms;
- Start datetime;
- End datetime;

And looks like this:

```
Object | Alarm | Start              | End                |                 
 obj1  | cell  | 2014-01-04 16:07:07| 2014-01-04 16:11:07|
 obj1  | loc   | 2014-01-04 16:08:07| 2014-01-04 16:09:07|
 obj1  | dc    | 2014-01-04 16:11:08| 2014-01-04 16:12:07| 
 obj1  | bat   | 2014-01-04 16:12:07| 2014-01-04 16:13:07| 
 obj2  | cell  | 2014-01-04 16:12:07| 2014-01-04 16:15:07| 
 obj2  | loc   | 2014-01-04 16:16:07| 2014-01-04 16:17:07| 
 obj2  | cell  | 2014-01-04 16:17:07| 2014-01-04 16:19:07| 
 obj2  | bat   | 2014-01-04 16:17:07| 2014-01-04 16:18:07| 
 obj3  | loc   | 2014-01-04 16:07:07| 2014-01-04 16:07:07| 
 obj3  | dc    | 2014-01-04 16:07:07| 2014-01-04 16:07:07|
```

What I want to do is to delete all the alarms for each object that occurred between start of the cell alarm and end of the cell alarm. So that the resulting dataframe must look like this:

```
Object | Alarm | Start              | End                |                     
 obj1  | dc    | 2014-01-04 16:05:07| 2014-01-04 16:06:07|     
 obj1  | bat   | 2014-01-04 16:12:07| 2014-01-04 16:13:07|   
 obj2  | loc   | 2014-01-04 16:16:07| 2014-01-04 16:17:07|   
 obj3  | loc   | 2014-01-04 16:07:07| 2014-01-04 16:07:07| 
 obj3  | dc    | 2014-01-04 16:07:07| 2014-01-04 16:07:07|
```

I attempted to do smth like

```
for obj in data['Object'].unique():
    dt = data[data['Object']==obj]
    start = dt[dt['Alarm']=='cell']['Start']  
    end = dt[dt['Alarm']=='cell']['End']
    mask = (dt['Start'] >= start) & (dt['End'] <= end)
    dt.loc[~mask]
```

However I'm getting an error plus, I can't get how to get the result for the whole dataframe.

Comment: What about  `obj2`, there are 2 `cell's` there, which one do have to use?

Comment: @Erfan that's one of the problems. We must get every Cell record start and end dates.

Comment: Oke, and why did `obj1`, `dc` suddenly change with start and end in your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to use `IntervalIndex` and listcomp. Create groupID `s` for each group start at `cell`. Call `groupby.groups` on `Object` and `s` to return a dictionary where each value is array of index of group. Create IntervalIndex `iix` from columns `Start` and `End`. Call listcomp on dictionary values and pass each array of index to `iix` to check `overlaps` and concatenate the result to mask `m`. Create mask `m1` to check on group of `Object` doesn't have value `cell`. Finally, slice `df` on `m | m1`

```
s = (df.Alarm.eq('cell') & df.Alarm.ne('cell').shift(-1, fill_value='True')).cumsum()
d = s.groupby([df.Object, s]).groups
iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.Start, df.End, closed='both')
m = np.concatenate([~iix[x].overlaps(iix[x[0]]) for x in d.values()])
m1 = df.groupby(df.Object).Alarm.transform(lambda x: x.ne('cell').all())

df[m | m1]

Out[187]:
  Object Alarm               Start                 End
2   obj1    dc 2014-01-04 16:11:08 2014-01-04 16:12:07
3   obj1   bat 2014-01-04 16:12:07 2014-01-04 16:13:07
5   obj2   loc 2014-01-04 16:16:07 2014-01-04 16:17:07
8   obj3   loc 2014-01-04 16:07:07 2014-01-04 16:07:07
9   obj3    dc 2014-01-04 16:07:07 2014-01-04 16:07:07
```